# 16.04 sda5_crypt setup page problem

Tags: command-line, keyboard, encryption

I have a fresh installation of 16.04 LTS. Right from the first restart after installation my sda5_crypt setup page looks like this half purple , half blank. [image: sda5_crypt setup page]

Also I am unable to key in the passphrase as my numpad does not work and even the LED of the numlock doesnot lightup.However I can see the characters **** stars on the field. As soon as I start typing in the numbers (my passphrase contains number) it takes me to the CLI interface where I can see the character ***stars. But numbers keyed in from my numpad doesnot work and I have to use numbers from my special character keys to setup the crypt.After that everything works fine.Below is the snapshot of my CLI interface
[image: CLI Interface]

Also I have observed a peculiarity in Ubuntu is that the numlock doesnot light up after boot although I have set it up in BIOS.